# Find non-alphanumeric characters in column in R

Tags: regex

I have a data frame named frame with IDs and names

```
1 marisa monte

2 dru hill

3 2pac

4 rã¶yksopp

5 cafã© del mar

6 maria bethã¢nia
```

This is the expected output

```
> no_alpha
[1] 4 5 6
```

I want to separate the names with any non-alphanumeric characters, expecting to get the indexes from rows with such characters. Said differently, if there's at least one character outside [a-zA-Z0-9], the row should be included. For some reason, I'm having difficulty doing so.

Below there are some variations I tried and their output. Regardless, after reading [this](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/regex), I still can't see my error. Clearly, I'm missing some important elements, since none of the returned vectors satisfy the condition "anything but alphanumeric".

```
no_alpha <- grep("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", frame$name)
> no_alpha
integer(0)
```

```
no_alpha <- grep("[a-zA-Z0-9]", frame$name, invert = TRUE)
> no_alpha
integer(0)
```

```
no_alpha <- grep("[^[:alnum:]_]", frame$name)
> no_alpha
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew returned an error.  

Error in grep("[^[:ASCII:]]", frame$name, perl = TRUE) : 
  invalid regular expression '[^[:ASCII:]]'
In addition: Warning message:
In grep("[^[:ASCII:]]", frame$name, perl = TRUE) :
  PCRE pattern compilation error
 'unknown POSIX class name'
 at 'ASCII:]]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need

```r
x <- c('marisa monte', 'dru hill', '2pac', 'rã¶yksopp', 'cafã© del mar', 'maria bethã¢nia')
grep("[^a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]]", x)
## => [1] 4 5 6
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/T3IbcK) online.

The TRE compliant regex matches

- `[^` - start of a negated bracket expression:

  - `a-z` - lowercase ASCII letters
  - `A-Z` - uppercase ASCII letters
  - `0-9` - ASCII digits
  - `[:space:]` - a POSIX character class matching any whitespace
- `]` - end of the bracket expression.

So, it matches any char other than the chars belonging to the ranges/POSIX character class listed above.